# Why am i not able to run the hadoop jar file, Everytime i run it says it says class not found exception itemclick.itemclick.ItemClick?

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, hdfs

I used the below code and i used the following command to run the hadoop jar file
**hadoop jar '/home/manthanjain/Hadoop-click-analysis/Itemclick.jar' itemclick.itemclick.ItemClick 
  '/Hadoop-click-analysis/Input' '/Hadoop-click-analysis/Output'**
Here input and output files are the hdfs files loaded inside hadoop

````
package itemclick.itemclick;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

public class ItemClick {

    public static class ItemClickMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            Text itemID = new Text();
            IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
            String[] tokens = value.toString().split(",");
            String[] timestamp = tokens[1].split("-");

            if(timestamp[1].equals("04")) {
                itemID.set(tokens[2]);
                context.write(itemID, one);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class SumReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>{

        public void reduce(Text itemID, Iterable<IntWritable> ones, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int count = 0;
            Iterator<IntWritable> iterator = ones.iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                count++;
                iterator.next();
            }

            IntWritable clicks = new IntWritable(count);
            context.write(itemID, clicks);
        }
    }

    public static class ItemClickMapper2 extends Mapper<Object, Text, IntWritable, Text>{

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String[] tokens = value.toString().split("\t");
            Text itemId = new Text(tokens[0]);
            int clicks = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
            IntWritable clicksFinal = new IntWritable(clicks);
            context.write(clicksFinal, itemId);
        }
    }

    public static class SumReducer2 extends Reducer<IntWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

        private Map<String, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        @Override
        public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            for (Text value: values) {
                countMap.put(value.toString(), key.get());
            }

        }

        public void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = sort(countMap);
              int counter = 0;
              for (String key: sortedMap.keySet()) {
                  if (counter ++ == 10) {
                      break;
                  }
                  context.write(new Text(key),new IntWritable(sortedMap.get(key)));
              }
        }

        public static Map<String, Integer> sort(Map<String, Integer> unsortMap) {

            List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> list =
                    new LinkedList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(unsortMap.entrySet());
//          for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : list) {
//              System.out.println("-----IN COMPARATOR METHOD------"+entry.getKey()+"  "+entry.getValue());
//          }
            Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
                public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1,
                                   Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
                    if(!o2.getValue().equals(o1.getValue()))
                        return (o2.getValue()).compareTo(o1.getValue());
                    else
                        return (o1.getKey().compareTo(o2.getKey()));
                }
            });

            Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : list) {
                sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }

            return sortedMap;
        }

            //context.write(itemId, key);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {

        Configuration conf1 = new Configuration();

        String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf1, args).getRemainingArgs();

        if (otherArgs.length !=2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: input_file output_file");
            System.exit(2);
        }

        Job job1 = Job.getInstance(conf1, "Item Click");
        job1.setJarByClass(ItemClick.class);
        job1.setMapperClass(ItemClickMapper.class);
        job1.setReducerClass(SumReducer.class);
        job1.setNumReduceTasks(10);
        job1.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job1.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job1, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job1, new Path(otherArgs[1]+"/temp"));

        if (!job1.waitForCompletion(true)) {
              System.exit(1);
        }

        Job job2 = Job.getInstance(conf1);
        job2.setJarByClass(ItemClick.class);
        job2.setJobName("sort");
        job2.setNumReduceTasks(1);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job2, new Path(otherArgs[1] + "/temp"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, new Path(otherArgs[1] + "/final"));

        job2.setMapperClass(ItemClickMapper2.class);
        job2.setReducerClass(SumReducer2.class);

        job2.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job2.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job2.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        if (!job2.waitForCompletion(true)) {
              System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: where are you running the jar on windows or Linux ??

Comment: @rahulsharma I am running the jar on Linux

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you

```
java -cp Itemclick.jar:./conf/:./lib:$HADOOP_CLASSPATH itemclick.itemclick.ItemClick  /Hadoop-click-analysis/Input  /Hadoop-click-analysis/Output
```

Comment: Nope,still facing the same error "class not found exception itemclick.itemclick.ItemClick"

Comment: Please do one thing extract your jar and see if the class is there or not expected package ??

Comment: I extracted the jar file and noticed the class ItemClick.class was present in the jar file

Comment: I just tried to compile the jar file using the command "java -cp Itemclick.jar: ItemClick.java" and noticed that it showed errors like package org.apache.hadoop.conf does not exist and 74 similar errors